# Using Javascript replace on a <td> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done quite a bit of searching on the site (and the web) in relation to my query but cannot get a straight answer. I need to remove the word "Other" from a dynamically created table. The code I am using is as follows:

```
<td id="testclass">Other Option</td>
```

```js
var str = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
var text = str.replace("Other", "");
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<td id="test">Other Option</td>
```

For some reason though, this does not work with the  element but it will work with p, span, div etc.

Can anyone shine some light on this? We have tried some jquery options to and still the same thing.

Here it is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robertsuperpixel/o9bjqr8n/)

Comment: verify your td id. Is it testclass or test?

Comment: If you inspect the DOM with the Web Developer console (or firebug, or whatever), you will notice that since the markup is invalid, the browser just writes the content of the tag as plain text and the tag is removed. For that reason you will never find the element with id "test"

Answer (score 7):

you're missing your whole table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td id="test">Other Option</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To explain : in absence of a table the `<td>` is omitted from your HTML, leaving that element's context without it's parent.
Since your TD has an ID which gets lost, JS in that case, on DOM ready cannot find this specific ID.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9bjqr8n/4/)